# Proving an upper bound for $f'(z)/f(z)$ where $f$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an analytic function in a neighborhood of $a$ and $f(a)\neq 0$. Prove for $\delta$ sufficiently small, $$ \sup_{|z-a|\leq \delta} \left | \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2\delta}$$

I know that $f(a)\neq 0$ means $f(z)\neq 0$ in a neighborhood of $a$ by continuity, but haven't been able to say much more. Other thoughts include expanding the Taylor series of $f'$ and $f$ and taking their ratio, and looking at $g(z)=\ln(f(z)), g'(z)=f'(z)/f(z)$.

Any help is appreciated, thanks very much.

Comment: $f(z)$ is analytic, so it has a Taylor series around $a$.  Use the ratio of the series for $f(z)$ and $f'(z)$.

Comment: $ \left | \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right| \to c$ finite when $z \to a$ so in a small neighborhood $|z-a| \le \epsilon$ we have $ \left | \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\right| \le 2(c+1)$. Pick $\delta \le \epsilon$ s.t $  \frac{1}{2\delta} \ge 2(c+1)$ and you are done;

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $g(z)=\ln f(z)$, then $g'(z)=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$.

Comment: Yes, I had thought of this but was not sure how it would help. I am then asked to find the supremum of the derivative of a function?